# Error when more than one property references navigation property EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

A Very common task in any model design is to have multiple foreign keys pointing to the same foreign table. I am using EF Code first in ef core 3.1 and have an issue with multiple foreign keys.

However when I attempt the following

```
public class MISObject {  

    [ForeignKey("StandardLookups"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? Enf_Item { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardLookups"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? Enf_Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardLookups"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? Enf_Cat { get; set; }

    public virtual MISStandardLookups StandardLookups{ get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error when I attempt to run migrations in EF Core 3.1, the reason I need 3 keys is they are three drop downs that link back to each other. Will be dependend dropdowns surely you should be able to have 3 foreign keys to the same Foreign table.

> There are multiple properties pointing to navigation 'StandardLookups'
> in entity type 'MISObject'. To define composite foreign key using data
> annotations, use ForeignKeyAttribute on navigation.

```
 public class MISStandardLookups : BaseModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LookupGroup { get; set; }
    public int LookupSubGroup { get; set; }
    public string LookupDescription { get; set; }
    public string   LookupText { get; set; }
    public string  LookupValue { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help

BTW I dont want to have three diff virtual properties like

```
public virtual MISStandardLookups StandardLookupsEnfItem{ get; set; }
public virtual MISStandardLookups StandardLookupsEnfType{ get; set; }
public virtual MISStandardLookups StandardLookupsEnfCat{ get; set; }
```

Sometimes EF can be so powerful but yet fall flat on its face with something so simple.

Comment: So, if either one of the keys match, you want the join to happen, or you want all of them to match together?

Comment: Well I need to look up data when using picks from drop down 1 , then it filters dropdown 2, SO I would guess when one of the keys match but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Your models should look like this:

```
public class MisStandardLookups
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LookupGroup { get; set; }
    public int LookupSubGroup { get; set; }
    public string LookupDescription { get; set; }
    public string LookupText { get; set; }
    public string LookupValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MisObject> MISObjectsItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MisObject> MISObjectsTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MisObject> MISObjectsCats { get; set; }
}

public class MisObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardLookups"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? Enf_ItemID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardLookups"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? Enf_TypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardLookups"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? Enf_CatID { get; set; }

    public virtual MisStandardLookups StandardLookupsItem { get; set; }
    public virtual MisStandardLookups StandardLookupsType { get; set; }
    public virtual MisStandardLookups StandardLookupsCat { get; set; }
}
```

And in the `Fluent API`, define relationship as:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
 {
     builder.Entity<MisObject>()
            .HasOne(x => x.StandardLookupsCat)
            .WithMany(x => x.MISObjectsCats)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Enf_CatID);

        builder.Entity<MisObject>()
            .HasOne(x => x.StandardLookupsItem)
            .WithMany(x => x.MISObjectsItems)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Enf_ItemID);

        builder.Entity<MisObject>()
            .HasOne(x => x.StandardLookupsType)
            .WithMany(x => x.MISObjectsTypes)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Enf_TypeID);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
 }
```

You said:

> BTW I dont want to have three diff virtual properties.

How should EF know which record of `StandardLookupsCat` point to when a record of  `MisObject` table have more than one FK filled?

Hope this helps.